# Ionic-3 app displays black screen on Android emulator and actual device

Tags: android, angular, ionic3, cross-platform

I have developed a mobile application in ionic3 which appears and works fine on browser but when I connect it with emulator or install apk on android device, only black screen is displayed on application startup. Let me know the solution if anyone ever faced this problem.

Comment: are you getting any error?. Did you try chrome://inspect

Comment: @Muhammad Mansoor, It's really hard to make any judgement with the description you provided. Can you please share your package.json file? Also may I know ionic version you are using? So that we can track/analyze the actual issue.

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Thanks for your response. It was facebook4 plugin that was causing problem. Removing it solved my problem.

Comment: @Sandy Thanks for your response. But the problem is solved now. I was using Ionic@4.1.2